# How to open a new window on click with python, selenium, pyvirtualdisplay?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, pyvirtualdisplay

I wrote a scraper in python which uses selenium, chrome and an added extension. The scraper works locally with the display visible but not when I try to run it in `headless` mode.

On the scraped website there is a button which automatically opens a new **window** (I cannot access it via URL in order to open it in a new tab).

```
click_button() # the button opens a new window with a confirmation button
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) # switching to the confirmation window
click_confirm() # when confirm is clicked the window closes automatically
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) # switching back to original window
```

Chrome doesn't work in headless when it has extensions installed so I'm forced to use pyvirtualdisplay.
The problem is that the `Display` of `pyvirtualdisplay` opens only one browser window, therefore the confirmation window never appears. How can I allow pyvirtualdisplay to open new windows and alternate between them?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that pyvirtualdisplay did open a window, however its size was 1px by 1px. Apparently setting up the webdriver window size the following way doesn't work properly with pyvirtualdisplay:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--window-size="1980,1080"')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=options)
```

Setting it up like bellow solved my problem and the window was of a normal size:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver.set_window_size(1980,1080)
```